# What defines the type of log data that goes into local1, local2, ect?

Tags: logs, rsyslog

I'm new to remote logging with rsyslog and having looked through [this page](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Rsyslog#Facility), I am unclear what each of the "locals" are used for.  (*EDIT - [this SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/115923/which-program-defaults-uses-syslog-local0-7-facilities) revealed a little more info*)

I initially set up rsyslog to dump `*.*` to the remote server, but it is sending everything.  I need to better understand what each of the locals do, so I know which ones to include or exclude to the remote server.

**Are there standards for what types of log data gets written to each local?**

Answer (score 2):

local facilities [are not used for anything specific](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog#Facility_levels)  and are application dependant. Usually consulting the documentation for the application will let you see what the default facility is and how it can possibly be customised.

See also [RFC3164](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3164)

Rather than focusing on local, focus on the application that is generating the message.

Sometimes using programname can help send specific messages to a destination.

e.g. I filter out dhcpd messages like this: In /etc/rsysconf.conf

`if $programname == 'dhcpd' then /var/log/dhcpd.log`

Comment: Is it possible to split logs into severity?  IE, I want to store local6 with severity 5-7 in one file, and severity 1-4 in another.